# model does not change angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have client list in a table. 
When I click on `editClient`, the name of the client will be displayed in an input text. This work perfectly.

```
 <body ng-app="myClientApp" ng-controller="myClientController">
        <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="chargerClients()">
               Charger Clients
        </a>                        
        <div ng-if="clients">
             <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="cl in clients >
                <td>{{cl.idClient}} </td>
                <td>{{cl.nomClient}} </td>

                 <td>   <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="editClient(cl.idClient,cl.nomClient)"></td>
              </table>
      <div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="id">
                <input type="text" ng-model="nom">
                <button ng-click="modifyClient()"> validate</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The problem is when I click on `modifyClient`, it keeps the same values and nothing happens. How can I fix this problem?

```
<script>
var app=angular.module("myClientApp", []);
app.controller("myClientController", function($scope,$http,$window) {

$scope.chargerClients=function(){

        $http.get("/clients")
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.clients=data;

        });
    };

    //load id and name 
$scope.editClient=function(idClient, nomClient){
$scope.id=idClient; 
$scope.nom=nomClient;}

//modifyClient

$scope.modifyClient=function(){
        var params="";
        var params = ({
                idClient:$scope.id,
                nomClient: $scope.nom});
$http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: "clients",
            data: params,
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $window.alert($scope.id+$scope.nom);
            $scope.chargerClients();
            $window.location.href = '/index.html'

        })
};

}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you edit and post your backend code so we can see how you persist the new data ? Also is the $window.alert(...) executed ?

Comment: i work with spring boot, when i update a client with postman, it works. yes windowalaert works also i did it to see the data. And i noticed that the name does not change even if i modify it in the input.

Comment: Is there an error from the http request?  There's no error catch.

Comment: @Gary Could you please create a fiddle? Would love to sort this out!

Comment: @phix yes there is no error, but the probleme when i try to update some fields, and i click on modify, i see no change in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using POST method in your modifyClient

Comment: The same thing it does not change, maybe have i add ng-change in the two fields(id and name)? but i don't knwo how it's really wreid!

Comment: How about updating yung url? from "clients" to "/clients"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you i solve it; i have to add link in ng-model:

```
`<ng-model="client.id">`
```

and in the script also:

```
$scope.client={}
$scope.editClient=function(idClient, nomClient){
$scope.client.id=idClient;
} 

$scope.modifyClient=function(){ 
var params=""; 
var params = ({ 
idClient:$scope.client.id 
});
```